# External CSS shows up in head tag, rather than separate file

Tags: css, asp.net, azure, google-chrome-devtools, bundling-and-minification

**PLATFORM**
* Asp.net Webforms - C#
* .Net 4.5
* Azure Web Hosting
* Chrome (43.0.2357.134 m) - Latest

---

**PROBLEM**
I am currently bundling CSS and Javascript using the ASP.NET Web Optimization Framework.  When testing in my local environment, all is working great.  You can clearly see that the aspx page is relatively small and the bundles are listed as separate individual files (cssAll & jsAll).

https://www.dropbox.com/s/dazt681qylk41hm/local-login-cache.PNG?dl=0

Once I deploy to Azure, the Javascript bundle does remain correctly linked and is cached, but the CSS bundle is no longer referenced. Instead, all CSS code is written directly into the head tag of the aspx file. This causes the aspx file to grow exponentially (from 5KB to 87KB) and it prevents the CSS from being cached. Interestingly, when I disable cache, the CSS file is now sent as a seperate file, and my aspx returns to its smaller size.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/eox7b0vc0mi27wo/azure-login-combined.PNG?dl=0

---

**MY THOUGHTS & QUESTIONS**

1. Is this normal behavior? Am I simply misunderstanding or misusing Chromes developer tools and/or the way CSS caching works?
2. If this is normal behavior, then why does my local environment respond differently to the Azure hosted environment?
3. If this is NOT normal behavior, then where could the issue be? (Please read considerations below to see what I have already tried or troubleshooted)

---

**CONSIDERATIONS**

- I have confirmed that all CSS, Javascript, and relevant directory structures are identical between my local machine and Azure. (Web deploy handled this well)
- I have tried the exact same tests with IE11 and Firefox, getting similar results.  If caching is disabled, the CSS comes seperately as intended, but if caching is enabled, then CSS is verbosely written into head tag of aspx page.
- Problem is not with Bundling because it is working. However, I have tried linking to each CSS file directly, rather than using the bundle, and the same oddity occurs.
- I have completely cleared browser cache (using the clear browsing history in chrome) between tests and have used multiple computers to test this, yet the results are the same.
- The page I am illustrating is very small, but other larger pages fair worse and can grow upwards of 600KB, due to this oddity.

Comment: My particular problem has been fixed and I have a theory as to what may have fixed it!  My web app was configured to run using https, but every time I accessed the production server, I was using standard http.  By setting a rule in my web.config to redirect http requests to https, my CSS is now properly linked and cached.  I will refrain from answering this question in case someone proves me wrong, but if no one objects within a week, I will mark this question as answered.

Answer (score 0):

The odd bundling behavior was finally resolved!

My local project was set to use "https" by default.  However, when browsing my production site on Azure, I noticed it was using standard "http".  Once I enforced all pages to be routed through "https" in Azure, my CSS was now properly bundled, linked and cached.

*- As a disclaimer, I honestly have no idea why this works, but it clearly is a fix for my particular problem.  If anyone can explain the "why", please feel free to do so.*